# Cannot install Rails3 on fresh Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ubuntu-10.10

Trying to install rails on a fresh copy of Ubuntu 10.10 and each time at gem install rails I get Error installing rails: mail requires i18n

I'm using the rvm approach to the install if that helps.  I've successfully got ruby 1.9.2 running and now this.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: This resolved itself after several install attempts.  Same methodology used each time.  It may have been an brief or intermittent versioning issue.

Answer (score 3):

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

I used Ryan Bigg's ["Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You"](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) blog post to install ruby & rails on my new ubuntu box.